# Difference between \let\foo\relax and \def\foo{} for disabling

Tags: macros, tex-core

When I want some macro to (temporarily) do nothing, I normally write

```
\let\foo\relax
```

But somebody asked me why I don't just do

```
\def\foo{}
```

and I realized I couldn't answer his question.

So, I have two questions:

1. Can somebody give a practical example of when the two would be different;
2. For the purpose of disabling a macro, which of the two is preferred?

Here's an example of how I normally use this:

```
\let\print@style\relax
\def\setprintstyle#1{\def\print@style{#1}}
\def\print#1{\print@style#1}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you

```
\def\foo{}
```

you are giving `\foo` an empty definition, but `\foo` still 'exists' using any of the tests used for this (such as `\ifdefined` or LaTeX's `\@ifundefined`). The same effect can be achieved by doing

```
\let\foo\empty
```

which is very slightly more efficient as it points to an already-used memory location (not a worry nowadays). When `\foo` has such a definition, it is expandable, and so

```
\edef\baz{\foo}
```

will result in `\baz` being empty, as `\foo` expands to nothing at all.

On the other hand

```
\let\foo\relax
```

makes `\foo` equal to the `\relax` primitive. That is a 'do nothing' operation, but importantly is *not* expandable. So in this case

```
\edef\baz{\foo}
```

leaves `\baz` with definition '`\foo`'. That can be useful: it's a way of temporarily preventing a macro from doing anything while retaining it's appearance in other code. On the other hand, sometimes you don't want that: it depends on the context. When `\foo` is equal to `\relax`, whether it is regarded as 'existing' by the various tests is more variable. TeX automatically creates control sequences equal to `\relax` in various cases, and so some tests will regard anything equal to `\relax` as 'not defined'.

So which is better depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just added my use case to my question.

Answer (score 7):

The first one lets `\foo` to  point to `\relax`, whereas the second to an empty macro. (Provided no-one re-defined `\relax` or `\empty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\let\foo\relax
\ifx\foo\relax True\fi
\def\foo{}
\ifx\foo\empty True \fi
\end{document}
```

For the purpose of undefining none is recommended, rather use

```
\let\foo\@undefined
```

At any stage you can test via `\meaning`

```
\let\foo\relax
\meaning\foo
```

will show `\relax`

**Edit**

As per revised question. To temporarily disable let the command to a relax **within a group** as shown:

```
\def\foo{AAAAAA}
{\let\foo\relax \foo}
\foo
```

Within the group the meaning of the command will be equal to `\relax` and do nothing. Outside the group it will have its value restored.

Comment: for undefining, `\let\foo\relax` is fine in plain TeX.  Otherwise I agree.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant "disabling" a macro instead of "undefining" it. I still want to be able to use it. I updated my question.

Comment: @job  You mean like if condition X do nothing else do something else (see edit)?

Comment: I updated my question with an example of how I normally use this.

Comment: @Job In your context `\relax` is fine.