# Version dependent package conflict

Tags: incompatibility, minted, eledmac

For testing purposes I am using a recent version of `minted` (from `TeX Live` 2015) with `TeX Live` 2014, containing also the 2014 version of `eledmac`. Between the two packages in these two versions there is a conflict, as `minted` requires `lineno`, which defines a command `lineref`, `eledmac` from 2014 also defining a macro of the same name.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \lineref already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2929 ...dref@undefined{#1}\l@dgetref@num{2}{#1}}

?
```

produced by

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{minted}  
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}       
\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

I imagine, although I'm not sure, that `minted` uses the `lineno` package to print line numbers with the listing, a feature not needed for my tests. The feature that made me use the 2015 version of minted is the `breaklines` not present in the 2014 version. Looking at the github repository of `minted` it seems that [first version introducing `breaklines`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/0103b4ef5059c0d9580869f5c8834970d23f68b6/source/minted.sty) already requires `lineno`.

Is there an easy way of dealing with such conflicts? Should I just change the order in which the packages are loaded, so that the `eledmac`-version of the `\lineref` is loaded instead of the `lineno` one, and then I just ignore the error message, as long as the output looks o.k.?

Comment: Ignoring error messages even if 'the output looks OK' is *not* wise. Is there some reason not to update to TL 2015? That seems the obvious solution. In general, these kinds of conflicts are to be expected if you mix versions.

Comment: With my version of TeX Live 2014, updated as much as possible, I get no error.

Comment: @egreg Yes, as long as I don't mix versions I get no error. But if I get it right the last version of `minted` in TeX Live 2014 doesn't offer the `breaklines` feature yet.

Comment: @cfr This is a question about an experimental setup, I'm not going to use it for production. Eventually it'll all get shifted to TeX Live 2015, but it's code I'm taking over from somebody else and first I need to understand how it worked in the environment it was built in, that is TeX Live 2014, before I start upgrading everything to TeX Live 2015. That said, if selectively using a newer version of minted creates a serious problem I can wait for `breaklines` until I shift everything else, but if it can be tricked into playing together it could be nice, and I'd learn something new.

Comment: But the code must have worked with TL 2014 with the version of `minted` then available. The 'environment it was built in' won't have included a future version, after all.

Comment: @cfr Well, it sort of worked, but even when setting `minted` into a `landscape` environment some lines extended beyond the page, so the `breaklines` feature does improve it a lot. The whole project is still in an experimental state anyway.

Comment: It isn't just part of the same version: the dependency is part of the same commit which makes it very likely that the dependency is required for the new feature. Otherwise, it wouldn't make sense to include it in the same commit. I don't really see the objection to running it with TL 2015 except to make life difficult for yourself. There doesn't seem any gain to doing so, really.

Comment: @cfr There are quite a few differences between the `eledmac` of 2014, 2015 and `reledmac`, so I was told at least, and advised to make a gradual shift. And thank you for the warning regarding mixing different package versions, I've explored the possibilities a bit now but understand that that's moving on thin ice, so it's better not to use it while still working from TeX Live 2014, keeping the code consistent, and only start using it after the switch to TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I'd install TL 2015 alongside TL 2014, copy the project and start upgrading the copy for use with 2015, while retaining the ability to compile the old version with TL 2014.

Comment: For future reference, the `lineno` package is used by `minted` to manage line numbers and line continuation symbols for lines that have automatic line breaks. It's only used on the lines that actually break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution how to make it compile withour error, and get output that on first view looks fine. Even the `linenos` option of minted appears to work.
`\meaning\lineref` shows `lineref`'s definition as in eledmac, which is what I want.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}  
\let\lineref\relax
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}       
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\autopar
\lipsum[1-2]
\endnumbering
\begin{minted}[linenos,breaklines]{tex}
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
This is a piece of LaTeX code. I am making it long enough so that it will have to be wrapped. 
\end{document}
\end{minted}
\meaning\lineref
\end{document}
```

[image: output sample]

As I don't fully understand the definition of `\lineref` in the `lineno` package, nor how `minted` makes use of it, (nor what exactly `\lineref` does in `eledmac`) I am using this with caution, always prepared for something to break, for testing purposes only, not for production. I can always comment out the `let\lineref\relax` line, rename the (2015) `minted.sty` file in my directory to something else so that latex doesn't use it anymore.

I got some inspiration from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49071/difference-between-let-foo-relax-and-def-foo-for-disabling).