# Why my minipage is going out of page?

Tags: minipage, geometry, mdframed, framed, mini-frames

```
]fichacatalografica.tex:47: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 47--47[]  \T1/lmtt/m/n/8 Modelo Cannico de TCC, Monografia, Dissertao, Tese ou
]fichacatalografica.tex:47: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 47--47\T1/lmtt/m/n/8 Relatrio de Ps--Doutorado da .... com abnT[]X2/ Nome do Autor. --
]fichacatalografica.tex:47: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 47--47[]\T1/lmtt/m/n/8 Programa de Ps--Graduao em Engenharia Eltrica -- PGEEL, Monday 14[]
]fichacatalografica.tex:47: Overfull \hbox (18.47636pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 47--47[]  []
]fichacatalografica.tex:47: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 47--47[]  \T1/lmtt/m/n/8 1. Palavra-chave1 2. Palavra-chave2 I. Orientador II.
]fichacatalografica.tex:47: Overfull \hbox (60.89018pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 47--48 [][]
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside,a5paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Memoir class conflict with datetime
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/memoir-class-conflict-with-datetime
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49071/difference-between-let-foo-relax-and-def-foo-for-disabling
\let\ordinal\relax
\usepackage{datetime}

% Comment this, unless you are debugging pages' badness Underfull & Overflow
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115908/geometry-showframe-landscape
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

% Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384885/package-hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{fichacatalografica}
    \vspace*{\fill}

    \begin{center}

        \hspace*{1cm}
        {Catalogação na fonte pela Biblioteca Universitária da ............. .......... ............ .}

        Arquivo compilado às \currenttime h do dia \today.

        \framebox[12.5cm]
        {
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

                \hspace{0.5cm}
                    1. Palavra-chave1
                    2. Palavra-chave2
                    I. Orientador
                    II. Universidade xxx
                    III. Faculdade de xxx
                    IV. Título
                \bigskip

                \hspace{7.75cm} CDU 02:141:005.7

            \end{minipage}
        }

    \end{center}

\end{fichacatalografica}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are forcing the `\framebox[12.5cm]` with `12.5cm`. Change it to `\textwidth` so it automatically adjusts itself and it shall be fixed.