# How to fix destination with the same identifier (name{page.A}) has been already used, duplicate ignored?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, page-numbering, warnings, abnt

The warning is:

```
test2.tex: destination with the same identifier (name{page.A}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

If I follow the `\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}` & `\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}`, from the question [pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (nam e{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18924/pdftex-warning-ext4-destination-with-the-same-identifier-nam-epage-1-has) it does fix the warning. But what the implications of doing that? Is there an alternative which does not change/disable the page anchors?

I tried adding `\pagenumbering{Alph}` as the other answer suggested:

> One way to avoid the problem is to change the (invisible) numbering style of the title page

But it does not fixed the warning. This is a simple document I could get which does the warning.

```
\documentclass[10pt,openright,twoside,a5paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Memoir class conflict with datetime
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/memoir-class-conflict-with-datetime
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49071/difference-between-let-foo
\let\ordinal\relax
\usepackage{datetime}

% Comment this, unless you are debugging pages' badness Underfull & Overflow
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115908/geometry-showframe-landscape
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

% Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384885/package-hyperref-warning-token
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

\titulo{Modelo Canônico de TCC, Monografia, ... de Pós--Doutorado com \abnTeX}
\autor{Nome do Autor}\local{Pais}\data{\today}
\orientador{Prof. Dr. Nome do Orientador}
\coorientador{Prof. Dr. Nome do Coorientador}
\instituicao{Departamento de Engenharia Elétrica e Eletrônica -- EEL
  \par
 Programa de Pós--Graduação em Engenharia Elétrica -- PGEEL}
\begin{document}
\pretextual
\imprimircapa
\imprimirfolhaderosto*
Without some text after that imprimirfolhaderosto*, the next command ignored somehow
\end{document}
```

---

Update

Systems versions after I added `\listfiles` to my preamble ([Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using)):

```
$ pdftex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX  (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)

using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.53.1; using libcurl/7.53.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.29; using 1.6.29
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.4.5; using LibreSSL 2.4.5
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with poppler version 0.53.0
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.4.21)  14 AUG 2017 22:16
entering extended mode
**./test2.tex
(test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2.cls
Document Class: abntex2 2016/02/26 v-1.9.6 abnTeX2
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip41
\lxvchars=\skip42
\xlvchars=\skip43
\@memcnta=\count79
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count80
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\stockheight=\skip44
\stockwidth=\skip45
\trimtop=\skip46
\trimedge=\skip47

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip48
...
\cftfigureindent=\skip180
\cftfigurenumwidth=\skip181
\c@table=\count135
\c@lotdepth=\count136
\cftbeforetableskip=\skip182
\cfttableindent=\skip183
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip184
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package array [2008/09/09] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2016/05/16] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package dcolumn [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package delarray [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package mparhack [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tabularx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty
Package: mempatch 2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \MakeTextUppercase on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \MakeTextLowercase on input line 50.
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen147
\Hy@linkcounter=\count137
\Hy@pagecounter=\count138

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count139

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4498.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4503.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4513.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4518.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4751.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count140

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5104.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen148
\Fld@menulength=\count141
\Field@Width=\dimen149
\Fld@charsize=\dimen150
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6358.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6363.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6366.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6373.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6378.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6383.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6388.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6428.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6432.
\Hy@abspage=\count142
\c@Item=\count143
\c@Hfootnote=\count144
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memhfixc.sty
Package: memhfixc 2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir cl
ass
\c@memhycontfloat=\count145
\c@Hpagenote=\count146
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count147
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count148

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip185
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bookmark.sty
Package: bookmark 2016/05/17 v1.26 PDF bookmarks (HO)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bkm-pdftex.def
File: bkm-pdftex.def 2016/05/17 v1.26 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
\BKM@id=\count149
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf
Language: portuges 2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/04/23 3.9r Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count150
\U@D=\dimen151
)
\l@brazil = a dialect from \language\l@portuges 
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 145.
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\enumitem\enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip186
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen152
\enit@toks=\toks23
\enit@inbox=\box29
\enitdp@description=\count151
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count152
\calc@Bcount=\count153
\calc@Adimen=\dimen153
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen154
\calc@Askip=\skip187
\calc@Bskip=\skip188
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count154
\calc@Cskip=\skip189
)

******************************************************
Stock height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Text height and width: 454pt by 278pt
Spine and edge margins: 85.35826pt and 56.9055pt
Upper and lower margins: 85.35826pt and 58.14961pt
Headheight and headsep: 12pt and 18.06749pt
Footskip: 25.29494pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 7pt and 42.9055pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 12pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 344.39996pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 12pt and 344.39996pt
******************************************************

\c@abntex@bookmarkcounter=\count155
\cftlastnumwidth=\skip190
\chapternamenumlength=\skip191
\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo=\skip192
\c@alineasi=\count156
\c@alineasii=\count157
\enitdp@alineas=\count158
\c@subalineasi=\count159
\enitdp@subalineas=\count160
\c@incisosi=\count161
\enitdp@incisos=\count162
\ABNTEXsignwidth=\skip193
\ABNTEXsignthickness=\skip194
\ABNTEXsignskip=\skip256
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks24
\inpenc@posthook=\toks25

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
...
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\datetime\datetime.sty
Package: datetime 2015/03/20 v2.60 Date Time Package

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count163
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\fmtcount\fmtcount.sty
Package: fmtcount 2015/05/05 v3.01

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks26
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks27
)
\XKV@depth=\count164
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\fmtcount\fcprefix.sty
Package: fcprefix 2012/09/28

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\fmtcount\fcnumparser.sty
Package: fcnumparser 2012/09/28
\fc@digit@counter=\count165
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks28
\ex@=\dimen155
)
\c@padzeroesN=\count166
\fc@tmpcatcode=\count167

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\fmtcount\fc-portuges.def
File: fc-portuges.def 2014/06/09
)
\@DT@modctr=\count168
\@ordinalctr=\count169
\@orgargctr=\count170
\@strctr=\count171
\@tmpstrctr=\count172
\@DT@loopN=\count173
\@DT@X=\count174
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\datetime\datetime-defaults.st
y
Package: datetime-defaults 2013/09/10
)
\@day=\count175
\@month=\count176
\@year=\count177
\c@HOUR=\count178
\c@HOURXII=\count179
\c@MINUTE=\count180
\c@TOHOUR=\count181
\c@TOMINUTE=\count182
\c@SECOND=\count183
\currenthour=\count184
\currentminute=\count185
\currentsecond=\count186
Package datetime Info: No datetime.cfg file found, using default settings on in
put line 308.
\@dtctr=\count187
\dayofyear=\count188
\dayofweek=\count189
LaTeX Info: Redefining \today on input line 736.
\dt@a=\toks29
\dt@b=\toks30
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
\Gm@cnth=\count190
\Gm@cntv=\count191
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count192
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen157
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen158
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen159
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen160
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen161
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen162
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen163
\Gm@dimlist=\toks31

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(D:\Cache\LaTeXTo
ols\7849f5862313964ed451cd855af48e56\test2.aux)
\openout1 = `test2.aux'.
...
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box30
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 26.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count193
)
...
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+cmss on input line 28.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1cmss.fd
File: t1cmss.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
) [1

{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2

]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has
 been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.30 W
      ithout some text after that imprimirfolhaderosto*, the next command ig...
[1


]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has
 been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.31 \end{document}
                    [2]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 31.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 31.

(D:\Cache\LaTeXTo
ols\7849f5862313964ed451cd855af48e56\test2.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 31.


 *File List*
 abntex2.cls    2016/02/26 v-1.9.6 abnTeX2
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document cl
ass
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   mem10.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir clas
s
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bookmark.sty    2016/05/17 v1.26 PDF bookmarks (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2016/05/17 v1.26 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
portuges.ldf    2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
datetime.sty    2015/03/20 v2.60 Date Time Package
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
fmtcount.sty    2015/05/05 v3.01
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
fcprefix.sty    2012/09/28
fcnumparser.sty    2012/09/28
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
fc-portuges.def    2014/06/09
datetime-defaults.sty    2013/09/10
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
geometry.cfg
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  t1cmss.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 31.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 31.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11133 strings out of 493324
 160841 string characters out of 3134268
 302523 words of memory out of 3000000
 14563 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 10381 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 39i,9n,35p,1000b,457s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
PDF statistics:
 48 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 5 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 9 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Your code does not compile for me. I get a missing `\begin{document}` error.

Comment: @cfr sorry, I fixed it. This problem, seems to be another question. `Without some text after that \imprimirfolhaderosto*, the next command ignored somehow`

Comment: With the change it does compile, but does not issue here the reported warning (nor any warnings).

Comment: Off-topic: As to the `\imprimirfolhaderosto*` "issue", just leave a blank line after it.

Comment: Perhaps a different distribution. I added my miktex version to the question, and also I added `\listfiles` to my preamble and updated the answer with then. You can see the `destination with the same` on the log. Now there are 2 of them, after I fixed the `\imprimirfolhaderosto*` issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pageanchors are needed for links which point to a page. E.g. from the bookmarks or from the table of contents or from some `\pageref{..}`.

If two pages have the same number then their pageanchors are the same and so links have no unique destination. This should be avoided.

If there is no link or bookmark that points to one of the problematic pages you can disable the anchors without problems. For a titlepage this is normally the case. So this here works okay in your example:

```
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\imprimircapa
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\imprimirfolhaderosto*
```

The main problem with this solution is to get the correct place to reenable the pageanchors, e.g. if hidden empty pages are involved one sometimes has to add some `\clearpage` and try out a bit.

Changing the pagenumber of one of the problematic doublette is also an option. In this case the main problem is to find the right location where to change the pagenumbering. This can be difficult if a class like yours does a lot through predefined commands. In your case this here works:

```
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\imprimircapa
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\imprimirfolhaderosto*
```

In other cases it could be also necessary to insert a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`.

Be aware that this solution also change the page number shown in a pdf viewer:

[image]